# Null Pointer Exception in copying files from remote

Tags: java, jsch

This question is related to the following answer posted by Zon.

[Transfer folder and subfolders using channelsftp in JSch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650013/transfer-folder-and-subfolders-using-channelsftp-in-jsch/37846036?noredirect=1#comment63154084_37846036)

I used the following code to copy a folder from remote to local.

```
public void downloadDir(String sourcePath, String destPath) throws SftpException { // With subfolders and all files.
    // Create local folders if absent.
    try {
        new File(destPath).mkdirs();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error at : " + destPath);
    }
    sftpChannel.lcd(destPath);

    // Copy remote folders one by one.
    lsFolderCopy(sourcePath, destPath); // Separated because loops itself inside for subfolders.
}

private void lsFolderCopy(String sourcePath, String destPath) throws SftpException { // List source (remote, sftp) directory and create a local copy of it - method for every single directory.
    Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = sftpChannel.ls(sourcePath); // List source directory structure.
    for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry oListItem : list) { // Iterate objects in the list to get file/folder names.
        if (!oListItem.getAttrs().isDir()) { // If it is a file (not a directory).
            if (!(new File(destPath + "/" + oListItem.getFilename())).exists() || (oListItem.getAttrs().getMTime() > Long.valueOf(new File(destPath + "/" + oListItem.getFilename()).lastModified() / (long) 1000).intValue())) { // Download only if changed later.
                new File(destPath + "/" + oListItem.getFilename());
                sftpChannel.get(sourcePath + "/" + oListItem.getFilename(), destPath + "/" + oListItem.getFilename()); // Grab file from source ([source filename], [destination filename]).
            }
        } else if (!".".equals(oListItem.getFilename() || "..".equals(oListItem.getFilename())) {
            new File(destPath + "/" + oListItem.getFilename()).mkdirs(); // Empty folder copy.
            lsFolderCopy(sourcePath + "/" + oListItem.getFilename(), destPath + "/" + oListItem.getFilename()); // Enter found folder on server to read its contents and create locally.
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting a null pointer exception at the following line which I am unable to resolve.

```
Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = sftpChannel.ls(sourcePath); // List source directory structure
```

I get that it has problem reading the source path but why? Please suggest.

Edited:

This is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" 4: 
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1720)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1526)
    at org.gradle.CopyTest.downloadDir(CopyTest.java:68)
    at org.gradle.CopyTest.main(CopyTest.java:97)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1543)
    ... 3 more
```

This exception is getting thrown:

```
         throw new SftpException(SSH_FX_FAILURE, "", (Throwable)e);
```

From this statement I believe:

```
((MyPipedInputStream)io_in).updateReadSide();
```

Comment: Because `sftpChannel` is null?

Comment: Yes, but why, it should be reading the source directory which is not empty..

Comment: And also sftpChannel was able to execute the command before this line..`sftpChannel.lcd(destPath)`

Comment: Please explain why is the sftpChannel is null...

Comment: I tried printing the values and both sftpChannel and sourcePath are not null and are printing.

Comment: Then you're probably pointing to the wrong line. Post your stack trace.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799006/jsch-get-fails-with-nullpointerexception. If you don't think so, please edit your question to include your code for creating the SFTP channel.

Comment: The code actually worked fine on other machine, the error was due to sftp not enabled on this particular machine.